# Can't launch Google Chrome after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: google-chrome, icons, launcher, 22.04

I've just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.  Chrome was working fine on 20.04
After first reboot, Chrome was missing from activities.

I realised I had used a third party repository so I uninstalled google-chrome-stable, removed all third party repositories and then reinstalled from the .deb package.
Still no google chrome in Activities.  There IS a Google Drive icon, which when I click on it opens a chrome browser.
I want the icon for Google Chrome to be in activities so I can get startup pages etc.
Also, when I do have Google Drive/Chrome running, I cannot pin the launch bar icon to the launch bar - the "Favourite" option is missing from right-click.

Any pointers as to what I can do?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can launch it. But you want to be able to do it a different way?

Comment: There are a number of steps to take before being able to launch Chrome from the taskbar. You can follow the steps in the GUI installation instructions set out [in this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-22-04/)

Comment: Thank you.  That tutorial ends with launching chrome from the terminal   Why does it not appear in the search or in applications? Can I make it?

Comment: once its running, is the icon for it in the dock (left panel)? If so, can you right click on it and `add to favourites`?

Comment: I can run it. But the 'Add to Favorites